# $yy'\sin x = \cos x(\sin x-y^2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have been given a differential equation for which we have to find the equation of curve . I tried it a lot but not able to proceed .

Can someone give me some hints .

$yy'\sin x = \cos x(\sin x-y^2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z= y^2$, then $z' = 2yy'$.  The equation becomes $z'\sin x/2 +(\cos x)z = \cos x \sin x,$ which is linear.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question has a nice solution (I think, because I am not expert at differantial equations). Anyway, let $y^2=u$ and $sinx=v$ then rewrite the equation as $$\frac{v.du}{2}=v.dv-u.dv$$. This doesn't look familiar, maybe $$v(\frac {v.du}{2}+u.dv)=v^2.dv$$ makes sense. $$ \int \frac {v^2.du}{2}+uv.dv=\int v^2.dv \Rightarrow \frac{v^3}{3}+C=\frac {v^2.u}{2}$$ (from partial differantial) so we rewrite the equation with $x$ and $y$ variables, we get $\displaystyle x=\arcsin\left ( \frac {2y^6+6C}{3y^4}\right)$

Comment: By the way, sorry for my bad language.

Comment: You are missing an integration constant. (and I would put the large formulas in display mode)

Comment: Thanks for your warning. İsn't it enough explanatory?

Comment: I mean LaTeX display mode math with `$$ ... $$` instead of the text mode `$ ... $`. And it is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I use \displaystyle code, but it is more useful.

Comment: How do you get to know we have to substitute this

Comment: Firstly, we don't have to substitute. It is to make things easier. $y.y'=(y^2)'$ and $\cos x=(\sin x)'$ so these substitutions should be made for an easier solution.